# Using Pivotal Tracker API to get all stories in Backlog or Current?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, pivotaltracker

I am using the pivotal-tracker gem: https://github.com/jsmestad/pivotal-tracker.

As a result, I'm easily able to stories by state, e.g.

```
project.stories.all(:current_state => 'started')
```

However, I'm wondering how to get all stories that correspond to the Backlog and/or Current columns.

It looks like this may have something to do with iterations but I can't figure that out.

```
project.iterations.find(????)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! For now I'm just separating out based on story state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out thanks to someone from Pivotal who pointed me to these code snippets: https://github.com/jsmestad/pivotal-tracker/blob/master/spec/pivotal-tracker/iteration_spec.rb

For example, to grab the `current` list:

```
@iteration = PivotalTracker::Iteration.current(@project)
```